# Delegate is nil, using storyboard embed segue

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, delegates, segue

I'm creating app with side menu like facebook. 
I have two containerView, which are connected with embed segue to their viewControllers.

When i swipe in my sideVC i need to call method in my mainVC to hide side menu, i'm try to use delegate but it's nil :(

Have my parent Class SlidingVC

**SlidingVC.h**

```
@class SlidingVC;

@protocol SlidingVCDelegate

-(void)slidingVCDidFinishLeft:(SlidingVC *)svc;
-(void)slidingVCDidFinishRight:(SlidingVC *)svc;

@end

@interface SlidingVC : UIViewController

@property(nonatomic, assign) id<SlidingVCDelegate> delegate;

@end
```

my left and right side controllers are his children

```
@interface RightPanelSlidingVC : SlidingVC
------------------------------------------
@interface LeftPanelSlidingVC : SlidingVC
```

and i have my mainVC what contains my side menu and using SlidingVCDelegate

```
@interface MainViewController : UIViewController <SlidingVCDelegate>
```

So i need to call in my mainVC method `-(void)slidingVCDidFinishLeft:(SlidingVC *)svc` or `right`

in my leftSideVC, when i make swipe i call:

```
- (IBAction)swipeLeft:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)sender {
    [self.delegate slidingVCDidFinishLeft:self];
    NSLog(@"Swipe left");
}
```

in my mainVC

```
@interface MainViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) LeftPanelSlidingVC *lvc;
@property (strong, nonatomic) RightPanelSlidingVC *rvc;

@end
......
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.lvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Left VC"];
    self.rvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Right VC"];
}
-(void)slidingVCDidFinishLeft:(SlidingVC *)svc{
    NSLog(@"Swipe left sucess!");
    [self animateSlidingVC:svc reveal:NO];
    [self shadowOpasity:0.0f from:2.0f to:0.0f inView:LeftContainer];
}


- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"embedRightVC"]) {
        self.rvc = (RightPanelSlidingVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
        self.rvc.delegate = self;
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"embedLeftVC"]) {
        self.lvc = (LeftPanelSlidingVC *)segue.destinationViewController;
        self.lvc.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

but in mainVC my delegate is nil, i don't know why.
As i think problem somewhere in embed segue

[app structure](https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1SGRAjJuB09PfDJ95o5XRoe_8yxkp41tPXeWN7pzyHNs/edit?usp=sharing)

[image: storyboard]

sorry for my English

Comment: @rdelmar sorry but maybe you can help, me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `prepareForSegue`
my panels were embeded in navController so i need to say that my navigationController is destinationController

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"embedRightVC"]) {
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            UINavigationController* navController = segue.destinationViewController;
            if ([navController.childViewControllers lastObject]) {
                RightPanelSlidingVC *rightVC = navController.childViewControllers[0];
                [self setRvc:rightVC];
                [self.rvc setDelegate:self];
                NSLog(@"Right Delegate");
            }
        }
    }
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"embedLeftVC"]) {
        if ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
            UINavigationController* navController = segue.destinationViewController;
            if ([navController.childViewControllers lastObject]) {
                LeftPanelSlidingVC *leftVC = navController.childViewControllers[0];
                [self setLvc:leftVC];
                [self.lvc setDelegate:self];
                NSLog(@"Left Delegate");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for all I know, by default `viewDidLoad` didn't automatically called in storyboard. You need to use `awakeFromNib` rather than `viewDidLoad`. that the reason why your `self.lvc` is null in `prepareForSegue:sender`.

Change `viewDidLoad` to `awakeFromNib` :

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.lvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Left VC"];
    self.rvc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Right VC"];
}
```

Comment: after that my lvc and rvc are dead in my mainVC and i get [UINavigationController animationStarted]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8168560